# magento 1.9.3.2 backend reset password error

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, prototype-js, password

I upgraded from magento1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.2, the site after the reset password can not click.
The chrome browser displays an error。

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost/js/index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototype/…s,mage/adminhtml/events.js,mage/adminhtml/form.js,scriptaculous/effects.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled. captcha.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class
>   is not defined
>       at captcha.js:25 (anonymous) @ captcha.js:25 (index):40 Uncaught ReferenceError: varienForm is not defined
>       at (index):40 (anonymous) @ (index):40

、

Comment: http://localhost/index.php/admin/admin/index/forgotpassword/ ,Seems to be related to the app / design / adminhtml / default / default / template / forgotpassword.phtml file。    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototype/validation.js,mage/adminhtml/events.js,mage/adminhtml/form.js,scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed the problem for my project. For me this looks like strange behaviour of the return **Content-type** header.

My solution is just to patch "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/forgotpassword.phtml" by adding one extra GET parameter in JS request url. I added "**c=auto**"

I changed:

```
src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototy......"></script>
```

To:

```
src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>index.php/x.js?c=auto&f=prototype/prototype.js......"></script>
```

I am not going too deep in the problem but by adding **c=auto** we force the php script that returns the JS content to set the correct **Content-type**. Probably this happens because the webserver recognises that the JS file is served from js/index.php and that is why the **Content-type** was **text/html** rather than **text/javascript**

I think that there are 2 solutions:

1. Fix the problem by changing webserver configuration.
2. Patch the template file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you clear Magento cahce and browser cache ?
It seems like you have used some extension to club the JS.
Please disable this extension and try again.

Thanks

Comment: hello, Pravin, My site frontend reset password can be work, but backend don't work, I tried clearing the brower cache and the magento cache.

Comment: This problem exists on all magento1.9.3.2 sites, in the browser chrome and firefox. Safari browsing can work properly.

Comment: Can you please disable that extension from app/etc/modules and try again.This is sure the js loading issue , you can check the console log to see the error